# A finite set is always compact

Tags: real-analysis

So I understand how it is always bounded and closed because it has non of its limit points but why does it not include any limit point?? Does this mean for any sequence 
$A_n$ 
it doesn't include any of the limit points.

Comment: Can you recall the definition of compactness?

Comment: A set K ⊆ R is compact if every sequence in K has a sub- sequence that converges to a limit that is also in K.

Comment: That's not the most general definition, but if that's the one you go on then here's how you could show it.

Get an infinite sequence $A_n$, you only have a finite number of points to consider. One of them has to appear in the sequence an infinite number of times. Suppose $a$ appears an infinite number of times in $A_n$. The sequence $\{a\}$ is a sub-sequence of $A_n$ that converges to a point in your finite set--obviously it converges to $a$.